# Java Queue Page Replacement

Tags: java, queue

I have a circular queue which should implement second chance page replacement algorithm. So that,lets say i have an array of 2D chars like below:

```
QUEUE: [a, 0] [c, 0] [b, 0] [k, 0]
```

and each element contains a char character and an extra bit.When we want to add element to queue which exists the reference bit should change from 0 to 1. Like below:

```
// Adding char 'a' to queue below
QUEUE: [a, 1] [c, 0] [b, 0] [k, 0]
```

This gives a second chance in order not to remove that char when new element should be added.The program should bypass the elements with bit 1, change their bit to 0(second chance) and add it into the needed index according to queue hierarchy.The problem occurs when adding new element which does not exist.So that, My code basically scans through queue array and adds to first char value where it sees index 0 and it creates problems in large inputs, since i loose hierarchy:

```
public char replace(char c) {
        char tmp = 0; // If nothing is replaced returns 0
        if (isempty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Queue is empty, cant dequeue");
        } else if (this.front == this.rear) {
            front = -1;
            rear = -1;
            numOfelements--;
        } else {
            for(int i = front; i <= rear; i = (i+1)%size ){
                if(queue[i][1] == '0'){
                    tmp = queue[i][0];
                    queue[i][0] = c;
                    break;
                } else {
                    queue[i][1] = '0';
                }
            }
        }
        return tmp;  
    }
```

For example : lets say the we add 'b' to queue below:

```
QUEUE: [a, 1] [c, 1] [b, 0] [k, 0]
```

When I add 'd' to it, it becomes like that:

```
 QUEUE: [a, 0] [c, 0] [d, 0] [k, 0]
```

After that when I try to add lets say 'p', it adds it to 'a', however it should add it to k.

Comment: Why would you do this? Is this a homework assignment? I can't imagine a reason for implementing a standard data structure.

Comment: Yes it is a homework, and i can not figure out that dequeue implemetation for 4 hours. Could you help me please?

Comment: The "else" part of your "if" sets queue[i][1] = '0' if it is not already. That causes the effect you ask about, but I bet there are more problems.

Comment: Googling java circular queues gives you lots of nice tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you explained does exactly what you explained it should do.
The result is what you'd expect from that algorithm.

However you want something different. It seems like what you want is that every time you change a `1` to a `0`, the corresponding queue entry is moved to the end of the queue.

It might be what you meant with

> and add it into the needed index according to queue hierarchy

but in that case you forgot to actually do that part.

I now assume that front and rear are variables marking the first and last index of the array:

```
} else {
    char currentChar = queue[i][0];
    for (int j = i; j < rear; j++) {
        queue[j][0] = queue[j+1][0];
        queue[j][1] = queue[j+1][1];
    }
    queue[rear][0] = currentChar;
    queue[rear][1] = '0';
    i--;
}
```

Keep in mind this piece of code is just to illustrate what you have to do and is not tested code.

---

Alternatively, if front and rear actually are supposed to tell you where to start and end (which is what I assume is the case because of the `%` operator), you would have to set front and rear to new values after you assign your char somewhere. However if it's supposed to be this way, this would invalidate your for loop, as you might actually start higher than rear and not want the for to stop.

It should look somewhat like this:

```
for(int i = front; i != rear; i = (i+1)%size ){
    if(queue[i][1] == '0'){
        tmp = queue[i][0];
        queue[i][0] = c;
        front = (i+1) % size;
        rear = i;
        break;
    } else {
        queue[i][1] = '0';
    }
}
```

Again: Keep in mind this piece of code is just to illustrate what you have to do and is not tested code.
This assumes that front and rear are within the array bounds!

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly.You can not imagine how happy i am. Althougth you say it was not tested, i guess you are man like compiler :).